# Why does adding a '0' to an int digit allow conversion to a char?

Tags: c++, char, int, type-conversion

I've seen examples of this all over the place:

```
int i = 2;
char c = i + '0';
string s;
s += char(i + '0');
```

However, I have not yet seen an explanation for why adding the zero allows for the conversion.

Comment: What is `char(i + '0');` in c++? (*This is an actual question.*)

Comment: @this it compiles on topcoder :/

Comment: @this, It's the integer `i` added with `'0'` promoted to an integer, the result being cast to a `char` with a functional-style cast, which does the same as a C-style cast.

Comment: What these answers fail to mention is that the character set is totally allowed to not be ASCII-compatible. However, if this happens to be the case, this will still work for `i∈[0, 9]` since the character codes of the digit characters are guaranteed to be contiguous. If you'd like an example of a character set that is not ASCII-compatible, have a look at EBCDIC. The digits `'0'`-`'9'` have the character codes 240-249 respectively.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at the ASCII table, [asciitable](http://www.asciitable.com/), you'll see that the digits start at 48 (being '0') and go up to 57 (for '9'). So in order to get the character code for a digit, you can add that digit to the character code of '0'.

Comment: C++ implementations are not required to use ASCII. Adding `0` to a value from 0 to 9 works because the C standard requires that the character codes for `'0'` to `'9'` be consecutive, in [lex.charset].

Answer (score 11):

When ASCII encoding is used, the integer value of `'0'` is `48`.

```
'0' + 1 = 49 = '1'
'0' + 2 = 50 = '2'

...

'0' + 9 = 57 = '9'
```

So, if you wanted convert a digit to its corresponding character, just add `'0'` to it.

Even if the platfrom uses non-ASCII encoding, the lanuage still guarantees that the characters `'0'` - `'9'` must be encoded such that:

```
'1' - '0' = 1
'2' - '0' = 2
'3' - '0' = 3
'4' - '0' = 4
'5' - '0' = 5
'6' - '0' = 6
'7' - '0' = 7
'8' - '0' = 8
'9' - '0' = 9
```

When ASCII encoding is used, that becomes:

```
'1' - '0' = 49 - 48 = 1
'2' - '0' = 50 - 48 = 2
'3' - '0' = 51 - 48 = 3
'4' - '0' = 52 - 48 = 4
'5' - '0' = 53 - 48 = 5
'6' - '0' = 54 - 48 = 6
'7' - '0' = 55 - 48 = 7
'8' - '0' = 56 - 48 = 8
'9' - '0' = 57 - 48 = 9
```

Hence, regardless of the character encoding used by a platform, the lines

```
int i = 2;
char c = i + '0';
```

will always result in the value of `c` being equal to the character `'2'`.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard says, in its [lex.charset] section “the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous” (quoted from draft N4659).

Thus, the value of `'1'` is '`0'+1`, and the value of `'2'` is one more than that, which is `'0'+2`, and so on. If `n` has a value from 0 to 9, then `'0'+n` is the value for the corresponding character from `'0'` to `'9'`.

(Unlike the earlier answers, this answer does not assume ASCII and shows how the property derives from the C++ standard.)

Answer (score 2):

It's based on ASCII values.  Adding the ASCII value of 0 which is 48 means that 48 + 5 will be 53 or ASCII 53 which is 5.

Google ASCII and find a good chart and study it.  It should make sense once you look at the values for each char (character).

Comment: C++ implementations are not required to use ASCII. Adding `0` to a value from 0 to 9 works because the C standard requires that the character codes for `'0'` to `'9'` be consecutive, in [lex.charset].

Answer (score 0):

`(char)(i+c)` where `c` is a `char` gives you a new `char` with an ascii value equal to (ascii value of `c`) + `i`. Since the ascii values of the digits 0-9 are sequential, `i+'0'` gives you the char corresponding to `i`, as long as `i` lies in the appropriate range.

EDIT : `(i+c)` is an int, as Jarod42 pointed out. Added a cast to maintain correctness.

Comment: C++ implementations are not required to use ASCII. Adding `0` to a value from 0 to 9 works because the C standard requires that the character codes for `'0'` to `'9'` be consecutive, in [lex.charset].

Answer (score -4):

A char will convert the integer to corresponding value based on ASCII value, So if you assign a value of 48 to a char it will store 0 since,48 is the ASCII value of 0.Correspondingly you add the ASCII value of 0 to any integer you need to convert to char

Comment: How does this add anything to the answers that already exist? In any event, it isn't completely correct. If you assign the value 48 to a char it will store 48 (which is `'0'` in a char variable). It wont store 0 since 0 != 48.

Comment: C++ implementations are not required to use ASCII. Adding `0` to a value from 0 to 9 works because the C standard requires that the character codes for `'0'` to `'9'` be consecutive, in [lex.charset].