# Ascii to Integer

Tags: java, string, ascii

I have a question about the following snippet:

```
while (str.length() > i && str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') {
    result = result * 10 + (str.charAt(i) - '0');
    i++;
}
```

Could someone tell me why `str.charAt(i) - '0'` is considered and what does it do?
Also, why is the result multiplied by 10?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does adding a '0' to an int digit allow conversion to a char?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422178/why-does-adding-a-0-to-an-int-digit-allow-conversion-to-a-char)

Answer (score 0):

By doing `Str.CharAt(i) -'0'` you just convert the caracter to the real number value provided that character is in 0 .. 9 range.

The `result = result * 10` thing is to "shift" previous result to the left (decimal base), since a new digit has been detected (and added to the result)

This code is probably doing a string to integer conversion, also a bad one since it seems that `12AAA34` would be converted to `1234` since non-digit charts are just skipped. It would be better if parsing stopped as soon as a non-digit char was found, like C `atoi` does (still accepting/skipping spaces)

Answer (score 0):

First of all this `Str.CharAt(i) - '0'` is considered because both `Str.CharAt(i)` and `'0'` returns Characters which have their ascii values to be integers.

It means that taking the value of the String `Str` fetch the character at index number `i` of the String(`Str`). For example consider this String `Emil`.
Then `"Emil".CharAt(0);` will give me `E`. But `E` has an ascii value of `69` which is an integer. Also `0` has an ascii value of `48`. So `"Emil".CharAt(0); - 0` is equivalent to `69 - 48`(thus the subtraction of two integer values) and returns and integer of `21`.

It(`Str.CharAt(i) - 0`) is added to the results of `results * 10` because `Str.CharAt(i) - 0` returns a Character which can also be recognise as an Integer(ascii) in java.

Take a look at [this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593074/calculating-with-the-char-variable-in-java) which also have an **ascii** **to** **character** table to make you understand more.